# Adding text to rectangle elements using D3 / SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm loading an external SVG file as below and need to add text to each rect that I can reference and manipulate. To do this I understand that I need to put each rect inside a group and insert the text element inside the same group. If possible I would like to do this through code as changing the structure of the SVG file would take forever as there will potentially be 100s of rects.

What is the best way to go about achieving this? I did look through some of the other questions however couldn't find the answer I need.

The best that I can assume at the moment is that I'll need to either select all rects and append the group or either loop through and select each rect individually?

floor.svg

```
    <rect id="SR001" x="288.62" y="220.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR002" x="288.62" y="266.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR003" x="288.62" y="312.49" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR004" x="288.62" y="375.62" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR005" x="288.62" y="421.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR006" x="288.62" y="467.49" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
<rect id="SR007" x="288.62" y="513.62" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
```

This is how the SVG file is loaded which seems to work fine. I have other functions that enable me to interact with the rectangles on certain mouse events etc.

javascript

```
d3.xml("floor.svg", function(xml) {
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);});
```

Comment: What does your data structure for the texts look like, how do you load that data, and how do you match the texts to the rectangles?

Comment: That's still a work in progress. I was trying to overcome the initial challenge of getting the text in the first place. The text will most likely come from an external CSV document. The row headings in the CSV will match the groups that have been created, "SR001" etc. I'm hoping it should then be quite simple to update the text displayed using data from the respective columns in the CSV. Might be back for more help when I get to that stage though :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd take is first extract data from rects, then remove all of the rects, and then recreate it all in structure you want it to be. To extract, you can use `selection.each(callback)`. Inside callback `this` points to the element, thus you can do eg `d3.select(this).attr('x')` to get its x attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg>
    <rect id="SR001" x="288.62" y="220.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR002" x="288.62" y="266.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR003" x="288.62" y="312.49" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR004" x="288.62" y="375.62" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR005" x="288.62" y="421.7" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR006" x="288.62" y="467.49" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  <rect id="SR007" x="288.62" y="513.62" class="st10" width="25.74" height="46.08"/>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var rectData = [];
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr('width', 600)
      .attr('height', 600);
    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .each(function() {
        var r = d3.select(this);
        rectData.push({
          id: r.attr('id'),
          x: r.attr('x'),
          y: r.attr('y'),
          class: r.attr('class'),
          width: r.attr('width'),
          height: r.attr('height')
        });
      }).remove();

    var g = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(rectData)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('id', function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    g.append('rect')
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.class;
      })
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.width;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.height;
      });

    g.append('text')
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Am I right in thinking that the above will only work with in line SVG and not when it is loaded from an external file? Ideally I would still want to load from an external file (due to the size of it) however I have already ran into a number of problems with this method.

Comment: I mean there isn't difference between having inline svg, or adding it to dom at runtime with appendChild or d3.append. Just watchout to call it after svg had been guaranteed to be loaded such as inside the callback